# C# Cross dependent interfaces issue

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

I already have two completed classes (EF domain models) with related references (One-to-Many):

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I need to use them through the interfaces in order to implement DI.
Such interface implementation obviously doesn't work:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    ICollection<IBar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public interface IBar
{
    IFoo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Could you, please, advice the proper way how it can be done?

Comment: I should use the concrete implementations of `Foo` and `Bar` directly. There is *almost* never a benefit to creating interfaces for your entity domain classes. You also would never want to inject entity classes. If you feel differently then please expand your question with why this is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the interfaces generic:

```
public class Foo : IFoo<Bar>
{
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : IBar<Foo>
{
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

public interface IFoo<T>
{
    ICollection<T> Bars { get; set; }
}

public interface IBar<T>
{
    T Foo { get; set; }
}
```